# MatLab SQLite & images

Tags: matlab, sqlite

I am trying to connect my matlab (r2011b) to a SQLite DB. I am using this code- http://sourceforge.net/projects/mksqlite/

I have only one problem with it, inside the DB I have Jpeg images which try to load.

When I use the query:
`res= mksqlite('SELECT Image FROM IMAGES limit')`, I get a struct with a 1*19628 cells of unit8.

When I load the image from a file using `imread('dbim.jpg')` I get a matrix of 500*500 uint8.

How do i convert the array into an image?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the size of the first cell in the cell array? `size(mycellarray{1})`, for instance.

Comment: Sorry, to be exact i get a matrix of 1*19628 of uint8. so the size of the first cell is 1*1